# Steam over proxy

Tags: steam

How do I run Steam from behind a proxy server?

Comment: Does your network filter any protocols or ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you could run Steam behind a proxy server, provided that the administrator opens the necessary ports.

You can find a good guide directly on Steam Support: [Required Ports for Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711).

Basically in order to just run steam you need:

> Steam Client
>
> ```
> * TCP 27014 to 27050 inclusive (Steam downloads)
> * UDP 4380
> ```
>
> Steamworks P2P Networking and Steam
>   Voice Chat
>
> ```
> * UDP 3478 (Outbound)
> * UDP 4379 (Outbound)
> * UDP 4380 (Outbound)
> ```

Than it really depends on which **multiplayer** game you want to play. In this case additional ports opening is required.

Instead, if you want to play only **single player** games, the steps before should work in 95% of games except those that requires additional connection requirements, like, for example, some Ubisoft games, some Game For Windows Live (GTA IV), etc.

Comment: This will only work for SOCKS proxies, i.e. proxies that tunnel arbitrary socket connections.

Comment: Just for clarification in addition to Drake's answer: It will **NOT** work for HTTP(S) proxies – so you might have bad luck if you try to run Steam during lunchtime at your office.

Comment: The list of ports on the Steam Support page shows more ports than this answer.

Comment: @Koraktor SOCKS proxies are not the only kind that tunnel arbitrary socket connections.

Comment: @DenilsonSá Not every port listed on that site is needed to just run Steam.