# What network port does Steam use?

Tags: steam

We have a white list of ports on our network, and the Steam client cannot connect to the server. Which ports do I need to open to make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steam over proxy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8780/steam-over-proxy)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's [a Steam Support page on this](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711):

> Your network must be configured to allow Steam access to the following ports (in order from highest to lowest priority for QoS users):
>
> **Steam Client**
>   UDP 27000 to 27015 inclusive (Game client traffic)
>   UDP 27015 to 27030 inclusive (Typically Matchmaking and HLTV)
>   TCP 27014 to 27050 inclusive (Steam downloads)
>   UDP 4380
>
> **Dedicated or Listen Servers**
>   TCP 27015 (SRCDS Rcon port)
>
> **Steamworks P2P Networking and Steam Voice Chat**
>   UDP 3478 (Outbound)
>   UDP 4379 (Outbound)
>   UDP 4380 (Outbound)
>
> **Additional Ports for Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2 Multiplayer**
>   UDP 1500 (outbound)
>   UDP 3005 (outbound)
>   UDP 3101 (outbound)
>   UDP 28960

Comment: I had a nearly identical answer about ready to post when you ninja'd me. :P

Comment: Ephemeral ports are assigned automatically by the TCP stack; none of these are ephemeral.  They should all be outbound, with the possible exception of the MW2 one.

Answer (score 0):

This (2024) is a bit different list than the first answer (2011).
From [link](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/2EA8-4D75-DA21-31EB)

```
To log into Steam and download content:

HTTP (TCP remote port 80) and HTTPS (443)
UDP remote port 27015-27050
TCP remote port 27015-27050


Steam Client

UDP remote port 27000-27100: Game traffic
UDP local port 27031-27036: Remote Play     ( share your Steam local multi-player 
TCP local port 27036: Remote Play           games with friends over the internet, ) 
UDP remote port 4380

Dedicated or Listen Servers

TCP local port 27015 (default): SRCDS Rcon port
UDP local port 27015 (default): gameplay traffic

Steamworks P2P Networking and Steam Voice Chat

UDP remote port 3478
UDP remote port 4379
UDP remote port 4380
UDP remote ports: 27014-27030
```

It is a bit unclear on how to prioritize multiplayer packets without prioritizing steam downloads.