# Unable to install Steam

Tags: steam

I am a first time Steam user. I am trying to download client for my Windows 7 machine. However I keep getting this error.

> Fatal Error: Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection.

I checked Steam forum and as per suggestion given there, I have disabled my Antivirus(AVG), but is it of no use. How can I fix this problem and install Steam?

Comment: If you're using Windows 7, UAC might be causing some issues.  Can you run Steam as Administrator?

Comment: @fbueckert: Thanks for your reply. I tried this too, but still got same error after some time.

Comment: Are you encountering the error when downloading Steam, installing it, or running it?  That's really important to figure out.

Comment: This is occuring while downloading.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  That error sounds like it finished downloading, and is in the process of installing or running itself.  It doesn't sound like an issue with downloading the client.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall or similar is blocking Steam from seeing the internet.

Comment: Actually I am downloading client for the first time. It shows the progres of download and then preempts with the mentioned error message.

Comment: @yogesh There are three times you "download" things, each different, so you really must be clearer. Have you already downloaded the installer? Are you now running the installer so that it can download the rest of the Steam client? Or is Steam finished installing and is now trying to update?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Installer is downloaded. Installer is being run to download the steam client. I have completely blocked my Antivirus(AVG 2013).

Comment: @yogesh: Were you trying to download Steam on your office/school/college network?

Comment: Is your firewall letting it through?

Comment: Are you on a router? Your router might be the issue, since Steam on your computer will try to talk to the Steam server in order to install it self and update. The router can block out the information. I setup an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem may be with your antivirus software. Even though you said you disabled it some AV products can still cause issues.

Per this page from Steam Support [Programs Which May Interfere with Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9828-SFLZ-9289)

> Anti-Virus Applications - Any Anti-Virus program could potentially block Steam and Steam game access, especially when not properly configured for use with Steam. Please make sure that Steam and all Steam games are listed as exceptions in these programs. If the issue persists, please try disabling or temporarily uninstalling the program to test the issue.

AVG is on the list with the following note:

> We recommend that applications listed in bold with a ( * ) symbol are fully uninstalled from your system if disabling them does not resolve the issue

This looks like it may be the solution from the information you have given.

I also suggest checking this list for other programs installed to see if there could be another conflict.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried all these things. Spoke to AVG tech support. They said there is no isssue with AVG.

Comment: Is it even possible to add Steam as an exception if you can't install it in the first place? :/

Comment: There is some steam.exe. when I click on it, it starts updating. I added that in exception list. No success.

Comment: I have Windows 7 and AVG.  It doesn't cause any issues.  I don't think this is the cause.

Comment: Any ideas then?

Comment: @yogesh Have you tried disabling your firewall?  How is your internet set up?  Are you behind a router, or are you directly connected to the modem?

Comment: @yogesh - Of course thats what they claim.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a router, make sure the following ports are set:

Steam Client

UDP 27000 to 27015 inclusive (Game client traffic)

UDP 27015 to 27030 inclusive (Typically Matchmaking and HLTV)´

TCP 27014 to 27050 inclusive (Steam downloads)

UDP 4380

Theres an answer on this site with the router info:
[What network port does Steam use?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34390/what-network-port-does-steam-use)

If you need help in setting up your router, just let me know.

And note that Antivirus is one thing, and a Firewall another.
Make sure that not just one of them allows Steam, but both!
Incoming and outgoing traffic!