# Steam installer unknown error

Tags: steam, technical-issues

So, its holidays and I decided install Medieval Total War to relax and chill, but when tried to install steam client to download the game I got the following error

[image]

I redownloaded the client, restarted computer, tried install as administrator, etc.

Someone know how to solve this? Without the name of error I dont know how to search for solution.

Comment: possibly relevant: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107665/unable-to-install-steam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend had same problem and he fixed it by accident. He has win 8 bdw. He fixed problem by changing install place from program files x86 to program files x64. Try it. You dont have nothing to lose.